# How To Speed Up KNN Algorithm

Tags: python, optimization, knn

I have a simple KNN algorithm that is used to predict the "yield" from a piece of data. There are around 27k rows in a pandas dataframe with 37 different columns. I have been trying to optimize hyper-parameters (the number of nearest neighbours) but running it with one parameter has already taken so long. I was wondering what ways could I improve the code below to make it run faster?

I have tried looking at possibly getting rid of the number of for loops but have no clue where to start really:

```
#importing modules
from math import sqrt

train_data = df_KNN[:23498]
test_data = df_KNN[23498:]

true_test = pd.DataFrame(df_KNN)
true_test = true_test.iloc[23498:, -1]
true_test = true_test.to_numpy()

#calculating "distance" between rows
def euclidean_distance(row1, row2):
    distance = 0.0

    for i in range(len(row1)-1):
        
        distance += ((row1[i] - row2[i])**2)

    return sqrt(distance)

def get_neighbours(train, test_row, num_neighbours):
    
    distances = list()
    
    for train_row in train:
        dist = euclidean_distance(test_row, train_row)
        distances.append((train_row, dist))
        
    distances.sort(key=lambda dis: dis[1])
    neighbours = list()
    
    for i in range(num_neighbours):
        neighbours.append(distances[i][0])
        
    return neighbours

def predict_classification(train, test_row, num_neighbours):
    
    prediction_list = []
    
    for row in test_row: 
        
        neighbours = get_neighbours(train, test_row, num_neighbours)
        output_values = [row[-1] for row in neighbours]
        prediction_list.append(output_values)
        
    prediction = np.mean(prediction_list)
    
    return prediction

def k_nearest_neighbours(train, test, num_neighbours):
    
    predictions = list()
    
    for row in test:
        
        output = predict_classification(train, row, num_neighbours)
        predictions.append(output)
        
    return (predictions)

test_pred = k_nearest_neighbours(train_data, test_data, 3)

from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
print(r2_score(true_test, test_pred))
```

I know I could use other modules but for this purpose I want to implement it from scratch. Cheers!

Comment: Not an answer but FYI KNN is quite slow. This is why it is not often used in high-frequency inference scenarios.

Comment: You should look into using sklearn's implementation. iirc they implement K-D trees which allow very efficient neighbor calculations. That will provide you with your largest speed improvement

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I'm thinking a PCA reduction from 37 to around 6 could potentially make it quicker but I'm not sure how much of a difference that could make.

Comment: I was going to look into sklearns implementation but for the sake of the project that this is for. I'm not allowed to use modules that implement it for me and rather do it from scratch.

Comment: Reducing dimensions will certainly help by a calculable scalar factor. I still think your bottleneck is due to the fact you're calculating 27k distances then sorting it.

Comment: If you're allowed to use numpy, use np.argpartition not sort, it'll be faster for many values of smaller k.

Comment: Yeah I can use numpy. How would np.argpartition be different to distances.sort? Isn't the sort method already O(n log n) which is good? I've looked am not too familiar with using np.argpartition for dictionaries either.

Comment: It seems there are some logical errors in the code. For example: in `predict_classification` function, why are you iterating over test_row? is it already just one row you passed from loop in `k_nearest_neighbours`

Comment: Also, post few rows and expected answer as example. That would help get dimensions right in refactoring the code.

Comment: Oh sorry that was just bad coding on my part. It's not actually a row I'm passing through in predict_classification. Instead I'm iterating through each feature. In this case in a row there are 37 columns. The "row" for loop in predict_classification goes over each of these columns.

Comment: fyi `np.argpartition` doesn't fully sort, it is like quick select, so it is more similarly `O(n)`